# Pass a variable from one razor web page to another

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

We need to pass data from one page to another using Razor Web Pages like a server-side include file.
I know that server-side includes are not supported so how can this be achieved without these. Is the only way, to create a helper method for this?

We need to hit the index file and load a settings file, grabbing the data from the settings file and calling methods (which is not shown to the user) and showing it on the index page. Really simple but Razor makes this task difficult.

We are just using razor web pages for this and not the MVC pattern.

Comment: I've created a functions file which will contain the methods I want to call on the pages of the site. I have added this file to the App_Code folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with Razor, it's just a template engine.

What you are saying is that you need to use some configuration data during response which is stored on the server and show it to the client in response. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

In that case in your action method you need to read your setting's file (you may read it with Server.MapPath, for instance, if you haven't already wrote your parser) and pass your values to the Index view either with your Model, or ViewBag. 
In other words, you shouldn't request file form server from your View in MVC pattern; all your data should be passed to the View from Controller.

Comment: Thanks, that's right. Razor is fine. We just need to grab variables and call methods in the settings file (reference it) on multi pages. We want to keep away from MVC for this and keep things really simple by having a few pages.